# removeChild loop (broken)?

Tags: javascript, html, removechild

The loop don't work and I think that's by this, maybe `list[i].removeChild(list[i]);` I want to remove the list with `lt` class.

```
function removeDone () {
  var lista = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if list[i].classList.contains('lt') {
      list[i].removeChild(list[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you're mixing up lista and list, additionally, you need to remove from lista, not lista[i].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use CSS selecters...

```
function removeDone() {
    var lists = document.querySelectorAll('li.lt');

    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++){
        lists[i].parentNode.removeChild(lists[i]);
    }
}
```